# In XSLT how to select a value from a node using IDs in which there is multiple of the same nodes?

Tags: xml, xslt, transformation

I am a trying to select values from multiple nodes that have the same name, but i am unable to create variables or IF statements that are successful.

In the example below i am trying to figure out how to create an IF statement in XSLT that says IF HouseID and HouseNo from the Houses Node matches the HouseID and HouseNo from the Streets Node then show the price of the matching node.

The example of the XML is below:

```
<pi:Houses>
 <pi:HouseID>1111</pi:HouseID>
 <pi:HouseNo>012</pi:HouseNo>
 <pi:Price>100000</piPrice>
</pi:House>

<pi:Streets>
 <pi:HouseID>1111</pi:HouseID>
 <pi:HouseNo>012</pi:HouseNo>
 <pi:Price>100000</piPrice>
</pi:Streets>

<pi:Houses> 
 <pi:HouseID>2222</pi:HouseID>
 <pi:HouseNo>098</pi:HouseNo>
 <pi:Price>9000000</piPrice>
</pi:House>

<pi:Streets>
 <pi:HouseID>2222</pi:HouseID>
 <pi:HouseNo>098</pi:HouseNo>
 <pi:Price>9000000</piPrice>
</pi:Streets>
```

I am currently trying to use

```
<xsl:if test ="pi:Houses/pi:HouseID = pi:Streets/HouseID">
<xsl:value-of select="pi:Houses/pi:Price"/>
</xsl:if>
```

But this gives me two values. 
I have tried using the position() operator but not joy.

Any suggestions would be great, thanks!

Comment: Can you show us a minimal but well-formed XML sample document together with minimal but complete XSLT that outputs the two values? It is not clear in what context or container you have the sample elements nor is the context of your `xsl:if` clear.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue in the past using variables.

In this example I have stripped out the namespaces to make it easier to read

```
<xsl:for-each select='//Streets'>
  <xsl:variable name='id' select='HouseID'/>

  <p>
    Street HouseID:<xsl:value-of select='$id'/><br/>
    House Price: <xsl:value-of select='../Houses[HouseID=$id]/Price'/>
  </p>

</xsl:for-each>
```